# Firmware AFL++ fuzzing fails

Tags: coredump, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop, fuzzer, afl-fuzz

I want to do Iot firmware fuzzing by AFL++ on a Linux system
https://blog.attify.com/fuzzing-iot-devices-part-1/

I have done the setup according to that link. when i run

```
sudo QEMU_LD_PREFIX=./squashfs-root/ ../AFLplusplus/afl-fuzz -Q -i input-xml/ -o output-xml/ -- ./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/xmlparser1 -f @@
```

it gives an error message asking to modify `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`:
I tried the solution given in here [AFL fuzzing without root - avoid modifying /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441062/afl-fuzzing-without-root-avoid-modifying-proc-sys-kernel-core-pattern)  to add `AFL_I_DONT_CARE_ABOUT_MISSING_CRASHES` in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern but it doesn't work maybe I did it wrong.

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do following:

1. sudo -i
2. echo core>/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

It should work.